# INVENTORY SYSTEM! Problems with tables

Tags: database, database-design, mysql-workbench, erd, inventory

[image: (Screenshot of current Database Schema) [Please Click]]

Hello guys! The picture attached is a screenshot of our current database design in MySql Workbench. We presented it into our professor and said that our schema was wrong particularly in the Product Categories (Cakes, Cupcakes, Pies), because it should've been inside the products table.

Can you help me improving this kind of schema by adding more tables and not just 5?

Comment: Sorry, can you specify your business/functional problem more deeply?

Comment: Hi! This is just a project in our school.

Comment: School or work, every project need requirements. The description of project is not clear

Answer (score 2):

Since your other tables (cakes, pies, etc.) don't add any new attributes, it's hard to envision why you need them. Wouldn't a row in `cakes` just be an exact duplicate of the row it references in `products`?

If you need to distinguish between product category, just add a column to your `products` table for the category.

P.S. Please don't get into the habit of prefixing all your table names with "tbl." This is redundant, because it's obviously a table if you can query from it. Just skip the "tbl." Likewise don't encode the data type in your column names. What if you need to change the data type someday? It would break all your queries.

P.P.S. Don't use `FLOAT` for currency—use `NUMERIC`.
See https://twitter.com/billkarwin/status/347561901460447232

Also read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the feedback! 



The reason why I am prefixing my  tables and datatypes, it's because our professor in that subject likes us to follow the correct naming conventions when it comes to entities in a database that is why.

Comment: Is there any way to add more tables in our inventory system? I'm still confused on what I am going to add, maybe employees?

Comment: Sorry for the late response

Comment: Okay, follow your instructor's rules for table and column naming. Just be aware that when you get into the real career, you won't use silly prefixes like that. But it's okay while you're in school.

Comment: As for more tables, I would expect that a `Sale` should reference a `Customer`. A `Sale` can also reference an `Employee`, for example if you need that employee to get credit for making the sale (maybe employees are paid on commission). And what if a customer buys several different pastries in one visit? Each `Sale` should be referenced by a `LineItem` table, where each `LineItem` is one product & quantity.